# How `const std::string& s = nullptr` works as an optional parameter

Tags: c++, reference, stdstring, initializer, nullptr

To my knowledge a reference cannot be null, but when I run code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void test(int i, const std::string& s = nullptr) {
  std::cout << i << " " << s << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  test(1, "test");
  test(2);
}
```

the optional parameter `s` can be null, and the code is built. What's more, when `test(2)` runs, the program throws exceptions instead of printing some random strings.

When I changed `s` to some basic type like int, it failed to compile, so I think the magic stays inside the string class, but how?

And what's more, how can I check if `s` is null or not? if I using `if(s==nullptr)` or `if(s.empty())`, it fails to compile.

Comment: Does it compile without the `const`?

Comment: @goodvibration no, it didn't, "non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'nullptr_t'"

Comment: it is not null reference, it creates `s` string object with nullptr as parameter to constructor `string(const char*)`.

Comment: @rafix07: Should a constructor be called when a reference variable is declared (and if yes, then why is it so only when that reference variable is `const`)?

Comment: Undefined behavior... you're toast now dude! The army of undefined-behavior-fanatic-zombies will downvote your question to the abyss of stack overflow, according to the sacred tradition of undefined-behavior blasphemy regulation.

Comment: @goodvibration Because only a const l-value reference can be bound to a temporary. Non-const cannot (l-value).

Comment: @goodvibration A reference to const can bind to a temporary (constructed in this case with a `const char*` pointer), a reference to non-const cannot bind to a temporary.

Comment: @goodvibration Constructor is not called because a reference is declared. It is called because the reference is bound to a temporary object, which needs to be constructed.

Comment: @goodvibration - There are good UB questions, and there are bad ones. This just so happens to be a decent one.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I agree. Also, there are good SO participants and there are bad ones. It just so happens that the majority goes under the second type.

Comment: This is madness. That's one of the reasons why implicit conversion is dropped in new (to dodge arguments that c++ is modern too), modern languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`test` initialized its argument by using constructor [number 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of `std::basic_string<char>`:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Since it needs to materialize a temporary (`std::string`) to bind to that reference. That is because a reference must be bound to an object of a correct type, which `std::nullptr_t` isn't. And said constructor has a *not null* constraint on the pointer being passed. Calling `test` without an explicit argument leads to undefined behavior.

To be perfectly clear, there is no such thing as a null reference in a well-formed C++ program. A reference must be bound to a *valid object*. Trying to initialize one with `nullptr` will only seek out to do a conversion.

Since a `std::string` is an object with a well-defined "empty" state, a fixed version can simply pass in a default initialized string:

```
void test(int i, const std::string& s = {}); // Empty string by default.
```

Once the contract violation is fixed, `s.empty()` should give meaningful results again.

Comment: maybe worth to mention it explicitly, just to be sure: references cannot be `NULL`/`nullptr`

Comment: @user463035818 - Sure

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the author of `test` *probably* wanted `void test(int i, const std::string& s = "")` or `void test(int i, const std::string& s = std::string{})`

Comment: And how to check if the basic_string takes a nullptr? I tried "string.empty()" but still got an exception.

Comment: @MartinBonner - Sure to that too

Comment: @user463035818 Relevant: [dcl.ref/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#5) *Note: In particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.*

Comment: @reavenisadesk The constructor will dereference the `nullptr` and most likely crash.

Comment: @reavenisadesk - You can't use a type's API to check a contract violation. The contract must be adhered to for the API to be guaranteed to even work. Consider stepping through the code, and then consulting the documentation.

Comment: Oh, does the exception throw from the constructor? As soon as it takes a nullptr as parameter? If this, then it is sure there's no way to check.

Comment: @reavenisadesk That's up to the implementation of your Standard Library. If you want to check whats going on step through the code with a debugger. Microsofts (and I bet every) Standard Library will try to find the length of the passed zero terminated string using `strlen()` which will dereference the `nullptr` and boom you go.

Answer (score 3):

Reference indeed can not be null, however `const std::string& s = nulltr` does not do what you think it does. When second parameter is not specified compiler will create a string object invoking `implicit` string constructor that takes a pointer to null-terminated string as first parameter. So `test(2);` invocation looks like this:

```
test(2, ::std::string(static_cast<char const *>(nullptr), ::std::string::allocator_type()));
```

Note that passing nullptr as this first parameter causes Undefined Behavior.